# bar graph with wrong width

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a bar graph for a dataframe contains multiple categories, with a different color for each category. Below is my simplified code and resulting graph. The top subplot is a regular bar graph in one color, the bottom subplot is color coded but the bar width is messed up. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'Cat': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                   'A': [2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 15, 18, 22, 23, 24, 25],
                   'B': random.sample(range(1, 20), 12)})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15/2.3))

ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.bar(df.A, df.B)
plt.xlim(0, 30)

ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
for cat in df.Cat.unique():
    df_ = df.loc[(df.Cat==cat), :]
    plt.bar(df_.A, df_.B, width=0.5)
    plt.xlim(0, 30)
plt.show()
```

[image: bar graph]

Comment: Use numpy arrays for plotting, `plt.bar(df_.A.values, df_.B.values, width=0.5)`.

Comment: On the bottom plot you do not specify a bar width, in the bottom plot you do. So what exactly do you mean with the bar width is messed up?

Comment: Thank you ImportanceOfBeingErnest ! Didn't know it makes such a difference

Comment: Solvaou: The problem is the bottom graph should be same as the top only with different color (besides the default bar width in top)

Comment: I see, but then it works like expected for me. Maybe there is an issue with `matplotlib`? Which version are you using (check with `matplotlib.__version__`)?

Comment: Solvalou: that was my initial thought too. It is unexpected and looks like a bug. I have matplotlib 3.1.1